# If $\{Z_n, n \geq 1\}$ is a martingale show that, for $1 \leq k < n$. $E[Z_n|Z_1,...,Z_k] = Z_k$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

If $\{Z_n, n \geq 1\}$ is a martingale show that, for $1 \leq k < n$.
\begin{equation}
        E[Z_n|Z_1,...,Z_k] = Z_k
    \end{equation}

I know that
$E[Z_{k+1}|Z_1,...,Z_k] = Z_k$ and $Z_{k+1} = E[Z_{k+2}|Z_1,...,Z_{k+1}]$. Plugging the second into the first gives $E[E[Z_{k+2}|Z_1,...,Z_{k+1}]|Z_1,...,Z_k] = Z_k$. If i can somehow show that this implies $E[Z_{k+2}|Z_1,...,Z_k] = Z_k$ then the rest should follow from induction. But I'm not sure why this would be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E[Z_{k+2}|Z_1,...,Z_k]$$ $$=E[E[Z_{k+2}|Z_1,...,Z_{k+1}]|Z_1,...,Z_k]$$$$=E[Z_{k+1}|Z_1,...,Z_k]=Z_k.$$ The first step is the tower property of conditional expectation.

Comment: This is correct. Cannot upvote because I reached the daily limit.

Comment: The tower property states that $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$ how does the first equality follow from this?

Comment: @Math_Day The general form of tower property says $E[X|\mathcal G_1|\mathcal G_2]=E[X||\mathcal G_2]$ if $\mathcal G_2 \subset \mathcal G_1$